# How to parse a single instance of multiple same name classes

Tags: jquery, django

When clicking on a link, it changes from like to unlike or vice versa but, the number of likes and unlike are supposed to change uniquely, and not every single one of the posts on the same page. A for loop in Django is used to call the posts, so they have the same class names. The jquery below is supposed to change the like count of a specific post, but it changes every single one due to the class name. How can this be done, please?

**jquery extract**

```
 var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
 $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
```

**full jquery code**

```
$('a.like').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $.post('{% url "posts:post_like" %}',
      {
        id: $(this).data('id'),
        action: $(this).data('action')
      },
      function(data){
        if (data['status'] == 'ok')
        {
          var previous_action = $(event.target).data('action');

          // toggle data-action
          $(event.target).data('action', previous_action == 'like' ?
          'unlike' : 'like');
          // toggle link text
          $(event.target).text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' :
          'Like');

          // update total likes

          var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
          $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 : previous_likes - 1);
        }
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Hi you are targeting all like button i.e :`$('a.like').` you can use `$(this)` instead . Declare this `var selector = $(this)` outside ajax call and then use `selector.data('action', previous_action == 'like' ? 'unlike' : 'like');` and `selector.text(previous_action == 'like' ? 'Unlike' : 'Like');` .

Comment: `$('a.like').data('action', ...)` changes **all** elements matching `a.like`. For the one you hooked the click on that was clicked, use `$(this)` or `$(event.currentTarget)`. (For the possibly child element of that where the click originated, use `$(event.target)`.)

Comment: Hello Thanks, I used the event.currentTarget and it worked by only changing now the link that is being clicked. The only issue is the numbers for the rest also keeps changing. It think it's due to the code below. Please help                                           
    `// update total likes
      var previous_likes = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
      $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'like' ? previous_likes + 1 previous_likes - 1);`  It's the last part in the question